# How to return a list of ints in Python C API extension with PyList?

Tags: python, c++, cpython, python-c-api, python-extensions

I am building a Python extension (`.pyd`) using Visual Studio 2015 C++ project and Python 2.7 32bit.

This is my `.cpp` file:

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject* GetTwoInts(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int random1 = rand() % 10;
    int random2 = rand() % 10;

    PyObject * python_val = Py_BuildValue("ii", random1, random2);
    return python_val;
}

static PyObject* GetListTwoInts(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int random1 = rand() % 10;
    int random2 = rand() % 10;

    PyObject *val1 = PyInt_FromLong(random1);
    PyObject *val2 = PyInt_FromLong(random2);

    PyObject *result = PyList_New(2);
    PyList_SetItem(result, 0, val1);
    PyList_SetItem(result, 1, val2);

    PyObject * python_val = Py_BuildValue("ii", result);
    return python_val;
}

PyMODINIT_FUNC initUtils(void)
{
    static PyMethodDef methods[] = {
        { "GetTwoInts", GetTwoInts, METH_NOARGS,
        "Get two C ints as a Python tuple with two random numbers" },

        { "GetListTwoInts", GetListTwoInts, METH_NOARGS,
        "Get a list with two random numbers" },
        { NULL, NULL, 0, NULL },

    };

    PyObject *m = Py_InitModule("Utils", methods);
}
```

This is the Python source code using the compiled extension:

```
import sys
import Utils
print help(Utils)
print Utils.GetTwoInts()
print Utils.GetListTwoInts()
```

This is the output:

```
(4, 2)
(91213912, 91213912)
```

So, the `Py_BuildValue("ii", random1, random2);` gave me a proper tuple with two random ints, just as expected. However, returning a list in the `GetListTwoInts` method gives me invalid numbers (looks like a reference value or a pointer?).

What should I do to return a list of real values instead in the `GetListTwoInts` method?

Comment: Why are you not returning `result`? That is your list.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, thanks that was it. I just had to return the `result`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can change the format of `Py_BuildValue` so that it builds a list instead of a tuple. Just use `"[ii]"` instead of `"ii"` as first argument:

```
static PyObject* GetListTwoInts(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int random1 = rand() % 10;
    int random2 = rand() % 10;

    PyObject * python_val = Py_BuildValue("[ii]", random1, random2);
    return python_val;
}
```

You can use `PyList_New` and `PyList_SetItem` if you want to create a list of dynamic size.

```
static PyObject* GetList(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int const N = 10;
    PyObject* python_val = PyList_New(N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        int r = rand() % 10;
        PyObject* python_int = Py_BuildValue("i", r);
        PyList_SetItem(python_val, i, python_int);
    }
    return python_val;
}
```

The problem with the `PyList` version in your question is that you are using `Py_BuildValue("ii", result)` on the list. This tries to create a tuple of two integers, where the first value is the `result` pointer casted to an integer.

Comment: thanks. However, I would like to return a list that contains an arbitrary number of items so supplying each item as an argument to `Py_BuildValue` is not an option. Is it possible to return the whole list without getting each of its item as an argument? Something like `Py_BuildValue([i], [1,2,4..n])`?

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov I edited my answer and added an example that uses `PyList_New` and `PyList_SetItem` to create a list with dynamic size.

Comment: or using `PyList_Append`, this could be : `PyObject *list = PyList_New(0);  iterate through the array/list;
    PyList_Append(list, PyFloat_FromDouble(element));
  return list;`